# Modifying the response body after an endpoint has completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use middleware to modify the response body *after* the endpoint has completed. I previously had trouble modifying headers below the call to next(), but by using OnStarting() I was able to change them.

The next problem is that trying to read the body of a response inside OnStarting will throw an exception. I did not have any luck using ActionFilters either.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMiddleware<EditResponseMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

public class EditResponseMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public EditResponseMiddleware( RequestDelegate next )
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    
    public async Task InvokeAsync( HttpContext context )
    {
        // Decrypt the incoming context.Request.Body
        
        context.Response.OnStarting(async () =>
        {             
            using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            // This will throw:
            await context.Response.Body.CopyToAsync( ms );
            byte[] content = ms.ToArray();
            
            // Encrypt the outgoing context.Response.Body
            
        });
        
        await _next( context );

    }
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support reading.
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsync(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsync(Stream destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

> // This will throw:
> await context.Response.Body.CopyToAsync( ms );
>
> System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support reading.

You're trying to copy the context.Response.Body stream (which is write-only) into a new memorystream that you then dispose.

To read the body stream you could for example do this:

```
   string bodyContent = new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
```

You can read below links to know more.

[How do I get the incoming request body and the outgoing response body in ASP.NET Core middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76316856/how-do-i-get-the-incoming-request-body-and-the-outgoing-response-body-in-asp-net) and [How to read ASP.NET Core Response.Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403941/how-to-read-asp-net-core-response-body)

**Update**

Do you try the below code ?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseMiddleware<EditResponseMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

public class EditResponseMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public EditResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;

        try
        {
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = memStream;

                await _next(context);

                memStream.Position = 0;
                string responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();

                memStream.Position = 0;
                await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            context.Response.Body = originalBody;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This produces the same error "System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable." If you try to read the response after calling next()

Comment: @Q-bertsuit  What's the project you use ? With the code you provide , I test it and I don't meet the same error.

Comment: Its an Asp Net 6 Web API project. Did you put the line AFTER calling next()?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit I test the code like my update.