# .NET6 minimal API: Manipulating response after .MapGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I need to manipulate the JSON after each `.MapGet()` in the same way (apply some transformations).

I always thought that we can setup middleware on response pipeline as well as on request pipeline by placing `.UseMiddleware()` (or `.Use()`) after `.MapGet()` like that:

```
[...]
app.UseMiddleware<MyRequestMiddleware>(); //It should be invoked before .MapGet()
app.MapGet(...);
app.UseMiddleware<MyResponseMiddleware>(); //It should be invoked after .MapGet()
await app.RunAsync();
```

In reality `MyRequestMiddleware` and `MyResponseMiddleware` are both pipelined to run before `.MapGet()`. How can I achieve "response pipeline" to run some transformation function for every endpoint? I know I can create a DI injected service and invoke the transformation in each endpoint but I'd rather not change the `.MapGet()` implementations and separate the transformations in another layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core middlewares that run before also run after (in a way). The request handling pipeline is build in the way that earlier middleware is (optionally) calling the next one ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)).

[image]

So if you want a middleware which does something after the next one then you just implement it in the following way:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);

        // your code that runs after the following middleware
    }
}
```

Or

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next(context);
    // your code that runs after the following middleware
});
```

In this pattern you can write a single middleware which does something before AND after.

`app.MapGet(...)` does not register middleware, it registers route handler. The  middleware which handles routes is registered with `UseRouting` if I remember correctly (also explicit call to it is not required).

See also [How do I get the incoming request body and the outgoing response body in ASP.NET Core middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76316856/2501279).