# How to get request body from HttpContext

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I'm trying to access the request body from an filter in an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API, but the request body is always empty, even when I pass a body.

Filter:

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using backend.Log;
using backend.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace backend.Filters;

public class ExceptionFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public int Order => int.MaxValue - 10;

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is Exception exception)
        {
            HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;

            RequestLog.Log(exception, request);

            context.Result = new ObjectResult(GenerateResponseBody(exception))
            {
                StatusCode = 500,
            };

            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }

    private static object GenerateResponseBody(Exception exception)
    {
        string message = "Erro inesperado no servidor.";

        if (exception.Message != null)
        {
            message += " " + exception.Message;
        }

        return new
        {
            message,
            variant = RequestVariant.Error.ToString(),
        };
    }
}
```

Request log:

```cs
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

namespace backend.Log;

public class RequestLog
{
    public static void Log(Exception exception, HttpRequest request)
    {
        request.EnableBuffering();

        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        string requestPath = request.Path;
        string requestMethod = request.Method;

        List<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> requestQuery = request
            .Query.ToList<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>();

        List<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> requestHeaders = request
            .Headers.ToList<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>();

        Stream requestBody = request.Body;

        string exceptionMessage = exception.Message;
        string exceptionStackTrace = exception.StackTrace;

        string logText = "";

        logText += "DateTime: " + dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "\n";

        logText += "Request:\n";
        logText += "\tPath: " + requestPath + "\n";
        logText += "\tMethod: " + requestMethod + "\n";

        string requestQueryLogText = GenerateRequestQueryLogText(requestQuery);

        logText += requestQueryLogText;

        string requestHeadersLogText = GenerateRequestHeadersLogText(requestHeaders);

        logText += requestHeadersLogText;

        string requestBodyLogText = GenerateRequestBodyLogText(requestBody);

        logText += requestBodyLogText;

        logText += "Exception:\n";
        logText += "\tMessage: " + exceptionMessage + "\n";
        logText += "\tStackTrace: " + exceptionStackTrace + "\n\n";

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("error.log", true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(logText);
        }
    }

    private static string GenerateRequestQueryLogText(List<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> requestQuery)
    {
        string logText = "\tQuery:\n";

        requestQuery.ForEach((KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> e) =>
        {
            logText += "\t\t" + e.Key + ": " + e.Value + "\n";
        });

        return logText;
    }

    private static string GenerateRequestHeadersLogText(List<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> requestHeaders)
    {
        string logText = "\tHeaders:\n";

        requestHeaders.ForEach((KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> e) =>
        {
            logText += "\t\t" + e.Key + ": " + e.Value + "\n";
        });

        return logText;
    }

    private static string GenerateRequestBodyLogText(Stream requestBody)
    {
        string logText = "\tBody:\n";

        requestBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(requestBody))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();

                logText += "\t\t" + line + "\n";
            }
        }

        return logText;
    }
}
```

Basically every time the controller throws an exception the filter catches it and then logs the error.

When it logs the error it catches each part of the request and the exception and put it on the log error file. Everything is fine but, when it gets to the request body its empty even when its not.

When I run the following request:

```
{ "login": "login", "password": "password" }
```

it puts the following in the error.log:

```
DateTime: 22/03/2024 17:43:00

Request:
    Path: /auth/sign-in
    Method: POST
    Query:
    Headers:
        Accept: application/json
        Connection: close
        Host: localhost:5071
        User-Agent: axios/1.6.7
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br
        Content-Type: application/json
        Content-Length: 58
        request-start-time: 1711140180634

    Body:
        
Exception:

    Message: testando log

    StackTrace:    at backend.Controllers.AuthController.SignIn(SignInDTO signInDTO) in C:\Users\jhose\desktop\projetos\day-manager\backend\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 24
   at lambda_method3(Closure, Object, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Comment: What does debugging shows? Is `reader.EndOfStream` returns `true`? I've tried to run your trigger on blank API and it thrown `InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed.` on the `reader.EndOfStream` call.

Comment: I allready fix what u are saying in the Program.cs file. When i run the code the body comes empty, its length is 0 so its allways considering that its in the end of the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnActionExecuting`/`OnActionExecuted` is too late to enable buffering, you need to do this earlier. For example you can add something like the following somewhere at the start of the middleware pipeline:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    await next();
});
```

While you can do this and it works (if placed correctly) I would recommend to consider using the build-in approaches for logging body/exception handling. See more:

1. [HTTP logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
2. [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0)
3. [How do I get the incoming request body and the outgoing response body in ASP.NET Core middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76316856/2501279)